# htaccess redirect from A record to www and new page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Need to redirect `example.com/page` to `www.example.com/page_2`. Can also be from `www.example.com/page` to `www.example.com/page_2`.  I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com/page [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/page_2 [R=301,L]
```

But that does not appear to work.

Comment: You could use some formatting to help the legibility of your question

Comment: Are you hosting multiple domains on this one account?

Comment: You also mention "A record" in the question title - what are you referring to? (That makes it sound like a DNS related question, but clearly this is not?)

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains just the `Host` header, as its name suggests (eg. `www.example.com`), it does not include the URL-path as well (ie. `/page`).

You match the URL-path with the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. So, try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page$ https://www.example.com/page_2 [R=302,L]
```

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK (if this is indeed intended to be permanent). 301s are cached hard by the browser so can make testing problematic.

Unless you have multiple domains on this account, you can remove the `RewriteCond` directive altogether.